# memcopy from array to new array with Dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy

I am trying to create a new packet with some extra header data  . I have old packet buffer . I want to add new header tag for VLAN ID . This is my approach .

```
//This is old buffer with values here .
u8_t* oldpacket = new u8_t[oldPacketLength];
```

So i created a new buffer for inserting the old data + 4 extra header byte

```
#define ETH_LENGTH_OF_ADDRESS 6
u32_t newPacketLength = oldPacketLength + 4 ;
u32_t remainSize = oldPacketLength-(2 * ETH_LENGTH_OF_ADDRESS);

u8_t* newpacket = NULL;
newpacket = new u8_t[newPacketLength ];

//get ethernet data upto dst mac & src MAC 
PPF_ETHERNET_HEADER pEthHeader = (PPF_ETHERNET_HEADER) pPacket;

//insert these MAC data to new packet
NdisMoveMemory(newpacket , &pEthHeader->aDstMac, 6);
NdisMoveMemory(newpacket + 6 , &pEthHeader->aSrcMac, 6);

//insert ID 0x8100 to new packet
PUSHORT pTpid;
Tpid = (PUSHORT)((PUCHAR)newpacket + 2 * ETH_LENGTH_OF_ADDRESS);
*Tpid = 802TPID;
TagHeader = (PVLAN_TAG_HEADER)(Tpid + 1);

//Insert remaining old data to new pcket
NdisMoveMemory(newpacket + (2 * ETH_LENGTH_OF_ADDRESS) + 4 ,oldpacket + (2 * ETH_LENGTH_OF_ADDRESS),remainSize );
```

I am getting different values when i run this . Any fault in NdisMoveMemory ?

Comment: @Ðаn - Note that he is using `new` in the above code.

Comment: Any mistakes in this code ?

Comment: *Any mistakes in this code?* -- You have a lot of magic numbers being used for some purpose 4, 6, 1, etc.), and a lot of pointer casting.  One would suspect *you* would know if there are mistakes, assuming you wrote this code.  You couldn't have come up with code looking like this by luck.

Comment: What do you mean by different values? It is unclear what result you are getting vs what you are expecting.